# Moq with Ninject Mocking, Kernel.GetMock<T> is not allowing multiple Setups on the same Mock object

Tags: unit-testing, ninject, moq

I'm building out Unit Test for our web application.  I'm starting with the service layer and mocking the repositories and services.  Our application uses Ninject IoC for pretty much everything...its neat and clean.  I'm having an issue using a second Setup on the same mock instance from the service.  Basically is not seeing it and the parameters/return values are not working like the others when debugging.  Please see the code for details.

```
    private MoqMockingKernel Kernel; //Ninject Mocking
    private Mock<IClaimRepository> MoqClaimRepository{
        get
        {
            if (Kernel==null)
                throw new InstanceNotFoundException("MoqClaimRepository, MockingKernel has not been initialized.  [TestFixtureSetup] failed.");
            return Kernel.GetMock<IClaimRepository>();
        }
    }
    private Mock<IContactRepository> MoqContactRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (Kernel == null)
                throw new InstanceNotFoundException("MoqContactRepository, MockingKernel has not been initialized.  [TestFixtureSetup] failed.");
            return Kernel.GetMock<IContactRepository>();
        }
    }
    private IClaimService MoqClaimService{
        get
        {
            if (Kernel == null)
                throw new InstanceNotFoundException("MoqClaimService, MockingKernel has not been initialized.  [TestFixtureSetup] failed.");
            return Kernel.Get<IClaimService>();  
        }
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Init(){
        Kernel = new MoqMockingKernel();
        Kernel.Bind<IClaimService, IDataService>().To<ClaimService>();
    }





    [Test]
    public void the_Export_should_return_results(){
        //Arrange

        MoqClaimRepository.Setup(x => x.Search(It.IsAny<IClaimSearchCriteria>()))
            .Returns(ClaimObjectsSetup.ClaimSearchResultsSetup);
        MoqClaimRepository.Setup(x => x.GetExportData(It.IsAny<string[]>()))
            .Returns(ClaimObjectsSetup.ClaimExportDataResultsSetup);        //NOT SEEING THIS SETUP INSIDE THE SERVICE
        MoqContactRepository.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<ContactCriteria>()))
            .Returns(ClaimObjectsSetup.ClaimSearchContactResultsSetup);
        //Act
        MoqClaimService.Export(new ClaimSearchCriteria());
        //Assert
        MoqClaimRepository.VerifyAll();
    }
```

Comment: See the line  //NOT SEEING THIS SETUP INSIDE THE SERVICE